# KnockoutJS - computed abservable and js object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to return a property of an observable but seem to be missing something.

```
self.SelectedAccountTypeID = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selectedAccountType.AccountTypeID();
});
```

I am trying to return the AccountTypeID property of selectedAccountType but this is not working

when I try

```
self.SelectedAccountTypeID = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selectedAccountType();
});
```

it works but returns a javascript object

Here is a fiddle with the code
http://jsfiddle.net/qafrD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `self.selectedAccountType` is an observable meaning that you need to invoke it like a function to retrieve its current value. The property "AccountTypeID" however is not an observable therefore you do not need parenthesis here.

```
self.SelectedAccountTypeID = ko.computed(function () {
    // Retrieve the value of the observable
    var selectedAccountType = self.selectedAccountType();

    // The value may be "undefined" or "null" if there has not yet been
    // anything stored in the observable
    if (selectedAccountType && typeof selectedAccountType.AccountTypeID != "undefined") {
        return selectedAccountType.AccountTypeID;
    }

    // Return a default value otherwise
    return null;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qafrD/1/

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, because your `selectedAccountType` is an observable you need to access its value with `selectedAccountType()`

So the correct syntax: `self.selectedAccountType().AccountTypeID;`

However because the `self.selectedAccountType()` can be null you need to check that first before accessing the `AccountTypeID` on it:

```
self.SelectedAccountTypeID = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.selectedAccountType())
        return self.selectedAccountType().AccountTypeID;
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmSfL/)